# How can I disable a button until a checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I would like to have a form button disabled, until a user clicks a checkbox.

This is the code i have (last part of the form)

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <input id="check" name="checkbox" type="checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox">
      Some Text Here
    </label>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="anmelden" class="button" id="btncheck" value="Send" />
```

I tried the following

```
$('#check').click(function(){

if($(this).attr('checked') == false){
     $('#btncheck').attr("disabled","disabled");   
}
else
    $('#btncheck').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

But this is not working and I am not sure why. I don't know how I can disable the button (should be disabled also visually).

**Solution (thanks to [Rory McCrossan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28428763/how-can-i-disable-a-button-until-a-checkbox-is-checked/28428821#28428821)): http://jsfiddle.net/0hvtgveh/**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your logic is a little off, try this:

```
$('#check').change(function () {
  $('#btncheck').prop("disabled", !this.checked);
}).change()
```

Note that the UI of the button does not update when disabled, however the `disabled` property does change. You would probably want to add some CSS styling to make it obvious that the button is disabled.

Also, I changed the code to use the `change` event instead of `click` to better cater for people who navigate using the keyboard.

Here's a full working example including the above amendments:

```js
$('#check').change(function() {
  $('#btncheck').prop("disabled", !this.checked);
});
```

```css
.form input[type="checkbox"] label {
  background: #000;
  height: 30px;
  border: none;
}

.form .button {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(46, 204, 113, 1.0);
  width: 180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  padding: 16px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.2s linear;
}

.form .button[disabled] {
  background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.form .button:hover {
  background: rgba(46, 204, 113, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
  <form>
    <div class="field">
      <label for="username">Name</label>
      <input id="username" name="username" type="text" value="Vorname Nachname">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label for="email">E-Mail Adresse</label>
      <input id="email" name="email" type="email" value="ihre@email.com">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label for="password">Handicap</label>
      <input id="password" name="password" type="text" value="z.B. 3">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label for="rpassword">Gäste</label>
      <input id="rpassword" name="rpassword" type="text" value="z.B. 2">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <input id="check" name="checkbox" type="checkbox">
      <label for="checkbox">Ich bin einverstanden dass mich die Leute kontaktieren</label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="anmelden" class="button" id="btncheck" value="Anmelden" disabled />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah yes, thank you. Is it possible to have the button disabled on default (when I first visit the page) and then turn it on? Right now the button is enabled on default.

Comment: You can set the `disabled="true"` property in your HTML manually, or you could fire the event immediately. I've updated my answer for you.

Answer (score 8):

Try with on change handler:

```js
$(function() {
  var chk = $('#check');
  var btn = $('#btncheck');

  chk.on('change', function() {
    btn.prop("disabled", !this.checked);//true: disabled, false: enabled
  }).trigger('change'); //page load trigger event
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
  <input id="check" name="checkbox" type="checkbox">
  <label for="check">Some Text Here</label><!-- for must be the id of input -->
</div>
<input type="submit" name="anmelden" class="button" id="btncheck" value="Send" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to update property, so use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `.attr()`

```
$('#check').click(function() {
    $('#btncheck').prop("disabled", this.checked == false);
});
```

A Good read [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#btncheck').attr("disabled",true);  //Initially disabled button when document loaded.
$('#check').click(function(){
    $('#btncheck').attr("disabled",!$(this).is(":checked"));   
})
```

> When you click on checkbox `.is(":checked")` return true if it is checked other wise return false. According to selection of your checkbox button it will enable/disable button.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0hvtgveh/5/)**

Comment: Run in mozilla firefox also. You can check demo

Comment: Yes, it runs good in all tried. What I was pointing out, yours only one here that would work for me in Chrome:)

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect condition in if statement.use:

```
$('#check').click(function(){
 if(!$(this).is(':checked')){
    $('#btncheck').attr("disabled","disabled");   
 }else
    $('#btncheck').removeAttr('disabled');
 });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1dn0k3xd/)**

Answer (score 0):

use  `if($(this ).prop( "checked" ))`,  instead of `if($(this).attr('checked') == false)`

http://jsfiddle.net/0hvtgveh/4/

```
$('#check').click(function(){

if($(this ).prop( "checked" )){
     $('#btncheck').attr("disabled","disabled");   
}
else
    $('#btncheck').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That is going to need a bit of logic :

```
   $(function(){
      const button = $('#submit'); // The submit input id 
      button.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('#checkbox').change(function() { // The checkbox id 
          if (this.checked){
            button.removeAttr('disabled')
            .css("cursor", "pointer");
          } else {
            button.attr('disabled', 'disabled')
            .css( "cursor", "not-allowed" );
          }
      });
  });
```

> Remember to set your css Submit Button attribute to `cursor: not-allowed;` hence can disable it upon page load.

PS : This code goes to the bottom of the page. If it turns out that you have a     separate file for it, do not forget to wrap it around:

`$(document).ready(function() {
    // code goes here
 });`

Answer (score 0):

I believe another way to handle this problem is by using document.getElementById:

```
if($(this).prop("checked")) {
    document.getElementById('#btncheck').disabled = false;
} else {
    document.getElementById('#btncheck').disabled = true;
}
```